# NSUrlSessionUploadTask Delegate method call twice sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I m in trouble with NSUrlSession Upload Task.  I'm uploading images with interval of 5 minutes which codes set by back end (php). When i click on upload button which is placed on a table cell i call notification center to perform upload task. for very first time when i upload it works proper but after upload when i try to upload images within a minuts it call its delegate multiple times.

button action code in cell.m:

```
- (IBAction)uploadnewBtn:(id)sender {

    touchText.alpha = 0;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endIgnoringInteractionEvents)];
    touchText.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"uploadBoastsDataBoaster" object:nil userInfo:nil];

}
```

Code for notification center method:

```
-(void)uploadBoastsDataBoaster
{
    NSLog(@"Counter >>>>>>>>>>>>>");

    [self.tableView1 reloadData];
    NSIndexSet * sections = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0];
    [self.tableView1 reloadSections:sections withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    NSLog(@"value:%@",model);

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        NSLog(@"There IS NO internet connection");

        CSToastStyle *style = [[CSToastStyle alloc] initWithDefaultStyle];

        style.messageColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self.view makeToast:@"There IS NO internet connection."
                    duration:3.0
                    position:CSToastPositionCenter
                       style:style];
        [CSToastManager setSharedStyle:style];


    } else {

[self OnSubmitImg:multipleImageData];
 }
```

final upload task method:

```
-(void)OnSubmitImg:(NSMutableDictionary*)image
{

    NSOperationQueue
    *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    // This creates basically a serial queue, since there is just on operation running at any time.
    [myQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:25.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *contentTypeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

    [request addValue:contentTypeValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];


    NSDictionary* dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

    NSString* uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:kUser_id];
    //  NSString *uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"FBid"]

    dictionary = @{@"user_id": fbEmail,@"fileToUpload[]":image};


    NSMutableData *dataForm = [NSMutableData alloc];

    for (NSString *param in [dictionary allKeys])
    {
        if([param isEqualToString:@"fileToUpload[]"])
        {
            for(int i=0;i<multipleImageDataObjects.count;i++)
            {



                UIImage *image = [multipleImageDataObjects objectAtIndex:i];
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3f);



                [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileToUpload[]\"; filename=\"%@%d.jpg\"\r\n", @"test", i] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                [dataForm appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
                [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            }
        }

        else
        {


            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            [dataForm appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }


    }



    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [urlSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:dataForm];

    [uploadTask resume];



}
```

Comment: Without knowing how you wire up your notification listener: maybe you have multiple objects listening for the `uploadBoastsDataBoaster` notification, and forget to unregister the old ones when registering a new one? This would explain why it works the first time (when there is only one listener around) but no longer works in subsequent attempts (when there are 2, 3.. listeners, each of which is triggered and runs the upload).

P.S.: a more concise code example (without button animation, reachability handling etc.) would make it easier for folks to help you out.

Comment: Could you please post the lines of code where you create the urlSession? I'd like to see the configuration of the session.